# How does one make required assemblies available for a CLI app?

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I created [a tool](https://github.com/fatso83/razor-cli) using a text editor and the Mono toolchain (on a Mac), and now I would like to know how to run the resulting `*.exe` on Windows without using the Mono runtime. I am not a .NET programmer, so I am unfamiliar with how one does this. I would like to end up with some way of just typing `razor-cli.exe arg1 arg2 ...` and it would just work (somehow).

This is how I currently run it (should work on Windows as well):

```
# Use "set MONO_PATH=...." on Windows
export MONO_PATH="lib/RazorEngine.3.8.2/lib/net45:lib/Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.3.0.0/lib/net45:lib/Newtonsoft.Json.8.0.3/lib/net45" 
mono razor-cli.exe partial.example.cshtml model.example.json
```

Here I add the paths for all the assemblies to `MONO_PATH`, which is used by the Mono runtime. I am guessing there is some similar mechanic for .NET, possibly using an additional file, specifying where the runtime can find the required dlls.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.mono-project.com/archived/best_practices/#monopath

> MONO_PATH overwrites the assembly loading process and will ignore assemblies that should be pulled from the Global Assembly Cache, it is merely a debugging tool and you should avoid its use.

So, don't do that.

See [MSDN: How the Runtime Locates Assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf(v=vs.110).aspx), basically: put the assemblies in the directory next to your executable, or put them in the GAC.

Comment: Thanks. Also useful : http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/application-deployment/

Comment: When using Nuget I would then need to move/copy the dlls from the subdirectories to the appdir after retrieval, right? Or is there a way of making the runtime use the correct dlls in the subdirectories?

Comment: What do you mean "after retrieval"? A build with NuGet packages will usually copy the necessary DLLs to the output directory.

Comment: See https://github.com/fatso83/razor-cli/blob/master/Makefile. Running 'nuget restore' downloads each dependency into its own subdirectory.

Answer (score 1):

It should work out of the box : http://www.mono-project.com/docs/faq/technical/#mono-platforms

The resulting command line should be :

```
razor-cli.exe partial.example.cshtml model.example.json
```

As for the required assemblies, if you didn't override the default resolution mechanism, the system will look in the application's folder and/or the GAC.

You might also find reading [this resource](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/application-deployment/#layout-recommendation) interesting.

It recommends to ship your application and all of it's libraries into the same folder as well as describing how the runtime will look for the required assemblies.

Comment: @JamesThorpe As I understand the Mono website, you don't have to do anything specific, just running the exe as one would normally do should be sufficient. I cannot test this though since I don't have a mono runtime available at the time

Comment: OK, I finally got hold of a Windows box, and it seems like all .NET exes (including ones produced by Mono) run without any special handling on Windows.